# Ignore unknown targets on multi-output regression

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to train a multi-output regressor, such that my `y_train` is a matrix that may contain unknown values (`np.nan`). A multi-output regressor, that does not natively support multi-output regression fits for each target (corresponds to the number of columns of the target matrix) a model.

I would like to ignore values in my target that are unknown, i.e. if the 3rd output of my target is unknown, the regressor corresponding to the target should not be trained for this instance.

Example:
Given the feature vector `(0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9)` and the corresponding target `(0.3, np.nan)`, I would like to train the regressor predicting `0.3` for this instance, but ignore the regressor for `np.nan`. Is there any elegant way to go about this?